# Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form and its working properly on Angular version below 13, When I try the same in Angular new version, it's showing me errors.

I have used FormGroup and FormArray and typecasted, but still getting the issue. What would be the fix?

Angular 11: [working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-aexzxn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Angular 15: [showing error](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-validation-angular-15-snyk3o?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts%3AL10,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Here is the ts code

```
form: FormGroup;
  items: FormArray;
  sum: number;
  data = [
    {
      name: 'Device 1',
      model: 'Model 1',
      serial: 'Serial 1',
      selection: 'takePayment',
      owedInDollars: 100,
    },
    {
      name: 'Device 2',
      model: 'Model 2',
      serial: 'Serial 2',
      selection: 'takePayment',
      owedInDollars: 200,
    },
    {
      name: 'Device 3',
      model: 'Model 3',
      serial: 'Serial 3',
      selection: 'takePayment',
      owedInDollars: 300,
    },
  ];
totalsum: number;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      items: this.fb.array([]),
    });
    const items = this.form.get('items') as FormArray;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
      items.push(
        this.createItem(
          this.data[i].name,
          this.data[i].model,
          this.data[i].serial,
          this.data[i].selection,
          this.data[i].owedInDollars
        )
      );
    }
    this.sumOfOwed();
  }

  createItem(
    deviceName: string,
    modelNumber: string,
    serialNumber: string,
    takePayment: string,
    owedInDollars: number
  ): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      deviceName: deviceName,
      modelNumber: modelNumber,
      serialNumber: serialNumber,

      dispute: '',
      return: '',
      takePayment: takePayment,
      reason: '',
      owedInDollars: owedInDollars,
    });
  }
  sumOfOwed() {
    this.items = this.form.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.sum = 0;
    this.items.controls.forEach((control) => {
      this.sum += control.get('owedInDollars').value;
      this.totalsum=this.sum
    });
    console.log(`Total Owed in Dollars: ${this.sum}`);
  }
  selectOption(item: FormGroup, option: string) {
    item.controls.dispute.setValue(option === 'dispute' ? 'dispute' : '');
    item.controls.return.setValue(option === 'return' ? 'return' : '');
    item.controls.takePayment.setValue(
      option === 'takePayment' ? 'takePayment' : ''
    );

    let total = 0;
    this.items.controls.forEach((control) => {
      let owed = control.get('owedInDollars').value;
      if (control.get('dispute').value || control.get('return').value) {
        total += owed;
      }
    });
    console.log(`New Total Owed in Dollars: ${this.sum - total}`);
    this.totalsum =this.sum - total
  }
}
```

Html code

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<table id="customers">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Device Name</th>
      <th>Model Number</th>
      <th>Serial Number</th>
      <th>Dispute</th>
      <th>Return</th>
      <th>Take Payment</th>
      <th>Owed in Dollars</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody formArrayName="items">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <td>{{ item.controls.deviceName.value }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.controls.modelNumber.value }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.controls.serialNumber.value }}</td>
      <td><input type="radio" formControlName="dispute" value="dispute" (click)="selectOption(item, 'dispute')"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" formControlName="return" value="return" (click)="selectOption(item, 'return')"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" formControlName="takePayment" value="takePayment" (click)="selectOption(item, 'takePayment')" [checked]="true"></td>
      <td>{{ item.controls.owedInDollars.value }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <td colspan="7" *ngIf="item.controls.dispute.value">
        <label>Reason:</label>
        <select formControlName="reason">
          <option value="">--Select--</option>
          <option value="Damaged">Damaged</option>
          <option value="Wrong Item">Wrong Item</option>
          <option value="Missing Part">Missing Part</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
<div><h2>{{totalsum}}</h2></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the typing of **[FormArray](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/forms/src/model/form_array.ts#L99)**

`FormArray<TControl extends AbstractControl<any, any> = any>`

In angular 14 It is important to specify expected type of the element in the FormArray

You could fix it by passing items FormArray expected type

```
 items: FormArray<FormGroup>;
```

**[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-validation-angular-15-rsxew6?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: I understand now, thanks. I have one more doubt, if you are ok, can you answer on the same thread? Actually on selection on dispute radio button, I'm displaying a drop-down with reasons. How can I display that drop down in the table below the respective selected row ,(1st row dispute selected, reason should be displayed below in the 1st row itself). For me it's displaying below the table

Comment: Hi Sure Could you share your the code in stackblitz?

Comment: It's in the same snippet. When you select the 1st radio button, drop-down is being added if you observe. I want that drop-down placement just below (enclose in the particular row). As of now dropdown is showing below the table.

Comment: Actually I'm looking to place that reason as a row. Example row1 if condition is selected below row as a reason row 2 and on selection of that radio button next row should be that reason. Anyhow thanks accepting the answer

Comment: can you help me with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75887120/implement-a-global-search-in-nested-mat-table

Comment: Hey @Teja sorry wil check for sure